# Alternative for nested loop operation in python?

Tags: python

I want a fast alternative of a nested loop operation in which the second loop occurs after some operation in first loop.

For example:

```
date = target_date_list = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date).strftime(f'year=%Y/month=%m/day=%d')

for date in target_date_list:
    folder = f'path_to_folder/{date}'
    for file in folder:
        //some operation
```

Comment: The nested for-loop is the way to go.

Comment: But the nested for loop seems too slow if the filer in a folder is too large and date is also large

Comment: `for file in folder:` here is iterating a string by character... I assume you actually want to iterate a directory on disk, right? What is your actual code doing? We can't optimize code that isn't actually doing anything useful.

Comment: actually the folder might be not only the one in the disk. It could be the aws s3 prefix (folder) also which we might iterate and perform the operation. So, nested for loop results in slow operation.

Comment: *Give more details about the actual problem.*

Comment: So i have the folder in the s3 bucket with the format of date as generated by date_range. Each folder have several files in it. Now I have to read all the files within the date_range and applied the operation on those files. Currently I am using the for loop as above and pd.read_csv to read the file and apply the operation which is takes long time to process

Answer (score 2):

There is no meaningfully faster alternative here. The inner loop's values are dependent on the value generated by the outer loop, so the micro-optimization of using `itertools.product` isn't available.

If you're actually iterating a directory (not characters in a string describing a directory), I'd strongly recommend using [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) over `os.listdir` (assuming like many folks you were using the latter without knowing the former existed), as it's much faster when:

1. You're operating on large directories
2. You're filtering the contents based on stat info (in particular entry types, which come for free without a `stat` at all; on Windows, you get even more for free, and anywhere else if you do `stat`, it's cached on the entry so you can check multiple results without triggering a re-`stat`)

With `os.scandir`, and inner loop previously implemented like:

```
for file in os.listdir(dir):
    path = os.path.join(dir, file)
    if file.endswith('.txt') and os.path.isfile(path) and os.path.getsize(path) > 4096:
        # do stuff with 4+KB file described by "path"
```

can simplify slightly and speed up by changing to:

```
with os.scandir(dir) as direntries:
    for entry in direntries:
        if entry.name.endswith('.txt') and entry.is_file() and entry.stat().st_size >= 4096:
        # do stuff with 4+KB file described by "entry.path"
```

but fundamentally, this optimization has nothing to do with avoiding nested loops; if you want to iterate all the files, you have to iterate all the files. A nested loop will need to occur somehow even if you hide it behind utility methods, and the cost will not be meaningful relative to the cost of file system access.

Answer (score -2):

As a rule of thumb, your best bet for better performance in a for loop is to use a generator expression. However, I suspect that the performance boost for your particular example will be minimal, since your outer loop is just a trivial task of assigning a variable to a string.

```
date = target_date_list = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date).strftime(f'year=%Y/month=%m/day=%d')

for file in (f'path_to_folder/{date}' for date in target_date_list):
    //some operation
```

Comment: This isn't actually doing the work the inner loop was doing. I'm a little unclear on what the OP is really doing, but if we assume they're trying to look at the files in a set of folders, simply moving the first statement into the loop doesn't actually save any of the inner loop work (unless you don't do it at all, in which case you're not doing the necessary work).